# Which type of 2 pin connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

I am having trouble identifying the correct connector. It is a two pin connector and I have attached a few pictures with dimensions (which may be off by a few hundredths of a mm).

[image: Overview]

[image: Front Dimensions]

[image: Side Dimensions]

Comment: It might help someone identify it if you could give a wider context, such as the make and model of the device it comes from. Also, are there any numbers or letters on it, perhaps a manufacturer's logo?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not have any numbers, letters, or logo. It is used with a 2017 ford f-250 fuel sending unit, like shown in this link: https://www.sunrisefordfontana.com/order-parts?path=%2Foem-parts%2Fford-fuel-pump-hc3z9h307ad%3Fc%3DZz1mdWVsLXN5c3RlbSZzPWZ1ZWwtc3lzdGVtLWNvbXBvbmVudHMmbD01Jm49QXNzZW1ibGllcyBQYWdlJmE9Zm9yZCZvPWYtMjUwLXN1cGVyLWR1dHkmeT0yMDE3JnQ9bGFyaWF0JmU9Ni03bC12OC1kaWVzZWw%253D

Comment: Enquiring on a Ford-focused car maintenance site might be more fruitful ;)